# how can i modify foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm wondering if it's possible to modify a Foreign Key?

```
FOREIGN KEY (member) REFERENCES scores (level) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

And I would like to change it to:

```
FOREIGN KEY (member, subject) REFERENCES scores (level, subject) ON DELETE set null,
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify the key in a single statement, see the [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) syntax, in which there is no ALTER CONSTRAINT available.

You must use 2 ALTER TABLE statements to accomplish what you want.

Delete the key in the first one using an ALTER TABLE DROP FOREIGN KEY.
Re-create it with the new columns in the second, using an ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY.

You can encapsulate both within a single transaction to make an atomic modification.

Comment: i write alter table teb drop foreign key; but it has this error:       error 1005: can't create table 'nehdi.#sql-6f0_2' (errno:150)

Comment: @mehdi: You can get details on that error by running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and reading the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

Answer (score 2):

In MySql, you can accomplish that by following [Tom Tresansky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314320/4929430) response, which will give us this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP FOREIGN KEY `key_name`;
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint_name` FOREIGN KEY (`new_key_name`) 
REFERENCES `other_table_name` ('other_table_id') ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the alter table command?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp