# How can I delete rows where its foreign key is NULL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables with names `tab1` and `tab2`.

tab1's p`rimary key is price` and `price is foreign key in tab2` and it is `on delete set null.`

When I delete one of `primary key` from tab1 that exists in tab2 the respective foreign key

is set to NULL.

Now I want to delete the row from tab2 where their foreign key is null.

I write this query but it does't work.

```
delete from tab2 where price = null.
```

Please help me in solving it.

Comment: You really should go through your questions and accept some answers. People take time out of their day to help you, the least you can do is click a check mark button.

Comment: yes your right. but i accept questions that was true.

Comment: -1 to TS, you are supposed to accept the most reasonable answer or alternative that you have had proposed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106889/how-to-insert-data-into-jtable
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187462/protected-void-paintcomponentgraphics-g
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902924/positioninterpolator-class
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314262/how-can-i-modify-foreign-key
 All of these have acceptable answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare NULL using =. You should use `IS NULL` instead

```
WHERE price IS NULL
```

From the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

> The NULL value can be surprising until
>   you get used to it. Conceptually, NULL
>   means “a missing unknown value” and it
>   is treated somewhat differently from
>   other values. To test for NULL, you
>   cannot use the arithmetic comparison
>   operators such as =, <, or <>.

But if you are already using `on delete set null`, why not simply change this to `on delete cascade` and save you the trouble from deleting the rows manually?

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from tab2 where price is null
```